# what is the relationship between increasing the number of cores and scalability?

Tags: parallel-computing

Whenever I increase the number of cores the speedup will increase. with this increasing can I consider the system as scalable?

I mean based on the speedup obtained for a different number of cores e.g. 10,20,30, is the system scalable with the increase of cores?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "scalable".  I think you'll find that there is no single definition for it.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem size (input data set and/or computation) is fixed , then **NO**. Amdahl's law says that. Speed up will be bounded by serial portion of the program.

If the problem size (input data set and/or computation) increases with the increase in the number of cores, then **YES**, Gustafson's law says that.